# Como substituir um índice por uma String

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou listando na tela números de **1** à **15** e verificando se o número é divisível por `3` e por `5` adicionando um texto quando verdadeiro, até aí funciona, mas, só que ainda exibe o número embaixo do texto, como faço para trocar o número pelo texto. Já utilizei o **replace**  sem sucesso:

```js
var nums = $(".nums");
 
  for(var i=1; i<16; i++) {

     if(i % 3 == 0) {
         var tres = i;
         tres = "Divisível por 3";
         nums.append(tres+"<br>");
     } else if(i % 5 == 0) {
         var cinco = i;
         cinco = "Divisível por 5";
         nums.append(cinco+"<br>");
     }

  nums.append(i+"<br>");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nums"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se armazenares em um array vais ter mais flexibilidade para tratar/precessar os dados da maneira que queres, neste caso incluir um separador `<br>` entre os elementos

```js
var nums = [];
for(var i=1; i<16; i++) {

    if(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
        nums.push(i+ " é divisível por 3 e por 5");
    else if(i % 3 == 0)
        nums.push(i+ " é divisível por 3");
    else if(i % 5 == 0) 
        nums.push(i+ " é divisível por 5");
    else
        nums.push(i);

}
$(".nums").append(nums.join('<br>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nums"></div>
```

Comment: Top Miguel, putz, realmente não tinha pensando em armazenar em um array. Muito obrigado man!